# Can I restrict comments on my answer?

Tags: support, answers, comments

Is it allowed to restrict the comments on my answer which is accepted by the user?

My answer does not require any comments and I want to protect it from chatty comments. How can I? I don't want to keep a watch on it and flag the chatty comments which may be attract the attention of moderator due to the low flag score.

Comment: Can you share a link to the post you're having problems with?

Comment: You are sure that your answer doesn't require any comments?

Comment: Related feature request: [Can we get a comments only lock?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171223/162704)

Comment: I'm fairly certain are worthy of comment, even if you don't feel that way. +1.

Answer (score 13):

You can't block comments on your posts.

If you find that your posts generate unnecessary comments, flag them. They'll be gotten rid of fairly quickly. If your posts *tend* to generate unnecessary comments, reflect back and see if there's something you might do differently to avoid them.

In general, if anything, good questions and answers tend to attract good clarifying comments. I'm particularly grateful for comments on my answers that discuss where I might improve.